# Improve Performance of VBA String Comparison

Tags: performance, excel, string-comparison, vba

I was wondering if this code could be sped up at all using another technique. The code doesn't take too long, but seeing as how how quickly something operates is usually what is wanted, I was curious if there is something I could do to increase the speed of it. The code is simply used to check every column against a template table to see if the value matches, if it doesn't it creates a report displaying information about the part and what the incorrect/correct value is.

```
Option Explicit

'Check values of table against template table
Sub checkTemplate(shnam1 As Worksheet, shnam2 As Worksheet, shnam3 As Worksheet)

    'Initalizes integers that will be used
    Dim rwIndex As Long             '"Item Attributes" row index
    Dim colIndex As Long            '"Item Attributes" column index
    Dim rowEnd As Long              'Last row in "Item Attributes"
    Dim colEnd As Long              'Last column in "Item Attributes"
    Dim tempIndex As Integer        

    Dim resRow As Long              'Current row in "Report" to paste
    Dim resCol As Long              'Current column in "Report" to paste
    Dim temp1 As String
    Dim temp2 As String

    'Gets bounds for "Item Attributes" table
    rowEnd = shnam1.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colEnd = shnam1.Cells(1, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Report Heading
    shnam3.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Oracle Part Number"
    shnam3.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Description"
    shnam3.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Attribute Name"
    shnam3.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Incorrect Value"
    shnam3.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Correct Value"

    resRow = 2                  'Set row for Results

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'From 2nd row to last row
    For rwIndex = 2 To rowEnd

        tempIndex = 3       'Template table index
        resCol = 1          'Set column for results

        temp1 = shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, 1)
        temp2 = shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, 2)

        'From 3rd column to last column
        For colIndex = 3 To colEnd

            'Compare selection in data to template table
            If (shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value) <> (shnam2.Cells(tempIndex, 1).Value) Then

                shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol) = temp1
                shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol + 1) = temp2

                'Copy attribute name
                shnam2.Cells(tempIndex, 2).Copy shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol + 2)

                'Copy incorrect attribute value
                shnam1.Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Copy shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol + 3)

                'Copy correct attribute value
                shnam2.Cells(tempIndex, 1).Copy shnam3.Cells(resRow, resCol + 4)

                resRow = resRow + 1                 'Move down a row in the "Report" table

            End If

            tempIndex = tempIndex + 1           'Increment through template table

        Next colIndex

    Next rwIndex

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this runs any faster for you:

```
Sub checkTemplate(shnam1 As Worksheet, shnam2 As Worksheet, shnam3 As Worksheet)

    Dim lCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim arrResults(1 To 65000, 1 To 5) As Variant
    Dim arrTable() As Variant
    Dim varCriteria As Variant
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim ResultIndex As Long

    With Application
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    arrTable = shnam1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For rIndex = 2 To UBound(arrTable, 1)
        For cIndex = 3 To UBound(arrTable, 2)
            varCriteria = shnam2.Cells(cIndex, "A").Value
            If arrTable(rIndex, cIndex) <> varCriteria Then
                ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = arrTable(rIndex, 1)
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = arrTable(rIndex, 2)
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 3) = shnam2.Cells(cIndex, "B").Text
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) = arrTable(rIndex, cIndex)
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 5) = varCriteria
            End If
        Next cIndex
    Next rIndex

    If ResultIndex > 0 Then
        With shnam3.Range("A1:E1")
            .Value = Array("Oracle Part Number", "Description", "Attribute Name", "Incorrect Value", "Correct Value")
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        shnam3.Range("A2:E2").Resize(ResultIndex).Value = arrResults
        shnam3.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort shnam3.Range("A1"), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        shnam3.Range("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If

CleanExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = lCalc
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error: " & Err.Number
        Err.Clear
    End If

    Erase arrResults
    Erase arrTable

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why, but that is returning about 200 more errors in the report.

Comment: really? It returned identical results for me on my (admittedly small) sample data set.  Are any of the extra errors being returned not supposed to be there?

Comment: I'm a little unfamiliar with how you compared the values with the values in the template table. The column number should line up with the row number in the table.

Comment: Yeah, that's why cIndex is used for both places.  The method I used was a filter, so when looking at column 3, it filters for all values not equal to cell A3 in shnam2 and records everything that shows, then for column 4, it filters for all values not equal to cell A4 in shnam2 and again records everything that shows.  Can you provide some sample data for where it's going wrong?

Comment: The error has to be coming from the comparison. Some of the values will be text, numbers, or just blank. That's the only issue I can see.

Comment: The report is showing certain values as having values that are different from the item database. Nothing was changed from the item database, just the incorrect value in the report isn't the same.

Comment: I have updated the code so that it no longer uses the filter method. See if that runs any faster for you.

Comment: It works fine for me.  At this point I'd have to see some sample data where the error is being produced

Comment: The col index is incrementing past 46 to 47, and that is where it is returning the subscript out of range.

Comment: Did you change how arrTable is defined?

Comment: Nope, I don't get why it's going past the UBound because when I put a break at the Next rIndex it shows it has being 46 and cIndex as being 32335 which are the correct dimensions of the data.

Comment: Out of curousity, in your sample data are you using strictly text? Or a mixture of numbers and text?

Cause I just changed, 
    `varCriteria = shnam2.Cells(cIndex, "A").Text`
to
    `varCriteria = shnam2.Cells(cIndex, "A").Value`
and it worked.

Comment: I was using text.  Glad you got it sorted.  I'll edit the answer to reflect that change.  Out of curiosity, was it any faster for you?

Comment: Yeah it was much faster, my orginal code took about 25 seconds, the filter method took about 15 seconds, and this one takes about 5 seconds.

Comment: I appreciate the help, now to figure out if I can speed up this ADODB importing.